# Java. Приведение типов

Tags: java, io

У меня есть метод который принимает из сокета объект а приводит его к `ArrayList` но IDEA подчеркивает желтым, и пишет:

> Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to
>   'java.util.ArrayList' less... (⌘F1)  Signals places
>   where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example:
>
> void f(HashMap map) {
>       map.put("key", "value");   }    Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details.

Но когда я добавляю `catch` блок с `CastExpression` или `ClassCastException` то мне и этот `catch` подчеркивает, мол не нужен он.

Объясните почему IDEA ругается, что хочет от меня?

```
private ArrayList<String> getObj(InputStream objIn) throws IOException {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(objIn);
            return (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

Comment: Чтобы вы убедились что там правда ArrayList, а не Object, как объявлено https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()

Comment: Это я понятно из комментария идеи. А что нужно для того чтобы JVM в этом убедилась? Я то уверен))))

Comment: сделай проверку instanceof

Comment: добавьте аннотацию @SuppressWarnings("all") к методу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В некоторых случаях от приведения из `Object` в конкретный тип не обойтись, однако каждый раз IntelliJ IDEA выделяет такое место в коде подобным образом. Кроме того, компилятор на таких местах, скорее всего, напишет предупреждение. Если вы уверены в своём коде и указанном типе, то можно использовать аннотацию `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, чтобы не получать лишние предупреждения. Такую аннотацию можно указывать над конкретной строкой, над отдельным методом или над всем классом, чтобы отключить предупреждения для соответствующего блока кода.